# How to create a new dataframe row with a new column for every combination of other two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a Pandas Dataframe which contains two columns `id1`, `id2` and I need to create a new column - `type` values with 4 rows for every combination of `id1`, `id2` from input and those 4 values should be `free`, `call`, `pri`, `status`.

**Input:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1,2,2],
                   'id2':[1,2,1,2]})
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

I tried to searching for functions in pandas documentation for this case and not even sure how to put it in words. So I just thought it would be better to explain here.

How can I to create a new column with values from 4 types.

**@jezrael:**

How do I merge this `type` column with the existing dataframe.

I have other columns too which contains some values as below

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

I just want to copy the values from existing input rows to output columns for `name` column. and there are many more such columns.

Comment: Dont add pictures as data, we cannot copy a picture.

Comment: Stackoverflow automatically suggested to add picture from imgur.com when I copy pasted the data. Didn't had an option not to add.

Comment: you add the data into the HTML snippet

Comment: Stack Overflow will prompt you to upload to imgur if the thing you're trying to paste is image data. We want text data. You might need to run your program from the command line and copy the data from there, if your IDE isn't displaying your data as text.

Comment: I copied it from excel sheet not the image.

Comment: As previously explained, text in Stack Overflow questions should not be supplied in bitmaps. I will cast a close vote for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need all combinations of all elements use `product` with columns and list and create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
from  itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1,2,2],
                   'id2':[1,2,1,2],
                   'name':['name11','name12','name21','name22']})

L = ['free', 'call', 'pri', 'status']

cols = ['id1','id2', 'name']
L1 = df[cols].values.tolist()

df2 = pd.DataFrame([x + [y] for x, y in (product(L1, L))], columns=cols + ['type'])
print (df2)
    id1  id2    name    type
0     1    1  name11    free
1     1    1  name11    call
2     1    1  name11     pri
3     1    1  name11  status
4     1    2  name12    free
5     1    2  name12    call
6     1    2  name12     pri
7     1    2  name12  status
8     2    1  name21    free
9     2    1  name21    call
10    2    1  name21     pri
11    2    1  name21  status
12    2    2  name22    free
13    2    2  name22    call
14    2    2  name22     pri
15    2    2  name22  status
```

Or use `cross join` with DataFrame created from list `L`:

```
cols = ['id1','id2', 'name']
L = ['free', 'call', 'pri', 'status']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type':L, 'a':1})

df2 = df[cols].assign(a=1).merge(df1, on='a').drop('a', axis=1)
print (df2)
    id1  id2    name    type
0     1    1  name11    free
1     1    1  name11    call
2     1    1  name11     pri
3     1    1  name11  status
4     1    2  name12    free
5     1    2  name12    call
6     1    2  name12     pri
7     1    2  name12  status
8     2    1  name21    free
9     2    1  name21    call
10    2    1  name21     pri
11    2    1  name21  status
12    2    2  name22    free
13    2    2  name22    call
14    2    2  name22     pri
15    2    2  name22  status
```

Comment: actually I have so many columns. Not just `id1` and `id2` which posted as to simplify the question. Is there any way to add this type column without much confusion?

Comment: @SukumarRdjf - Sure, use `L1 = df[['id1','id2']].values.tolist()`

Comment: When i run the first option, i get the error as follows "NameError: name 'product' is not defined" (using pandas 0.25)

Comment: @jezrael Could you please see the updated question and let me know if there is any thing that is possible for that case.

Comment: filling a column for dataset with 3 million rows, `itertools.product` filled all 16GB of RAM. the pandas cross join worked very well for me. Thanks @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a combo of repeat and assign:

```
df = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(df))]
        .assign(v=len(df)*['free', 'call', 'pri', 'status'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data = list()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for value in ['free', 'call', 'pri', 'status']:
        data.append((row.id1, row.id2, value))
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id1', 'id2', 'type'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```py
id1 = np.array([1,1,2,2]).repeat(4)
id2 = np.array([1,2,1,2]).repeat(4)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':id1,
                   'id2':id2})
df["type"] = ["free", "call", "pri", "status"]*4
print(df)
```

Output is

```
    id1  id2    type
0     1    1    free
1     1    1    call
2     1    1     pri
3     1    1  status
4     1    2    free
5     1    2    call
6     1    2     pri
7     1    2  status
8     2    1    free
9     2    1    call
10    2    1     pri
11    2    1  status
12    2    2    free
13    2    2    call
14    2    2     pri
15    2    2  status
```